# What's the difference between var p = new Person() and var p = Person()?

Tags: javascript, object, difference

For example I have this function:

```
function Person(name, age){
this.name = name;
this.age = age;
this.planet = "Earth";

//and so on
}
```

And I can create new object:

```
var person = new Person("Natasha", 24);
```

and

```
var person = Person("Lisa", 32);
```

I know that 1st thing is right, but second is working too. Can you, please, tell me, why not to use thing without `new`?

Comment: Maybe this question helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript Look for the answer of JulianR

Comment: The second one is not working :) It pollutes window object.